# How does one configure Quartz.net to run a job when another job hasn't run for a period

Tags: c#, quartz.net

Assume I have two Quartz.net jobs that

- downloads a CSV file with a delta of changes for a period (e.g. 24h) and then imports the data (called `IncrementalImportJob`)
- downloads a CSV file with a all the records and then imports the data (called `FullImportJob`)

The requirement is that `IncrementalImportJob` at a minimum once for the period (e.g. 24h). If that window is missed, or the job didn't complete successfully, then `FullImportJob` should run instead. The reason is that changes for that (missed) day would not be imported.  This condition is rather exceptional.

The FullImportJob requires resources (time, CPU, database, memory) to import all the data, which may impact other systems. Further, the delta of changes are often minimal or non-existent. So the goal is to favour running the `IncrementalImportJob` when possible.

How does one configure quartz.net to run `FullImportJob` if `IncrementalImportJob` hasn't completed successfully in a specific time period (say 24h)?

Searching the web for "quartz.net recovery" and "quartz.net misfire" doesn't reveal whether its supported or whether its even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is native misfire handling in quartz.net, however it only goes as far as specifying whether the job should fire [immediately again, or after a period of time or a number of times after misfiring.](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/quartz-scheduler-misfire-instructions.html)

I think one option is to handle this internally from IncrementalImportJob.

```
try
{
    //download data
    //import data
}
catch (Exception e) //something went wrong
{
   //log the error
   UpdateFullImportJobTrigger(sched);
}

//Reschedule FullImportJob to run at a time of your choosing. 
public void UpdateFullImportJobTrigger(IScheduler sched)
{
   Trigger oldTrigger = sched.getTrigger(triggerKey("oldTrigger", "group1");
   TriggerBuilder tb = oldTrigger.getTriggerBuilder();

   //if you want it to run based on a schedule use this:
   Trigger newTrigger = tb.withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
  .withIntervalInSeconds(10)
  .withRepeatCount(10)
  .build();

   sched.rescheduleJob(oldTrigger.getKey(), newTrigger);

   //or use simple trigger if you want it to run immediately and only once so that 
   //it runs again on schedule the next time.
}
```

This is one way of doing it. Another would be abstracting this logic to a maintenance job that checks the logs every so often and if it finds a failure message from IncrementalImportJob, it fires FullImportJob. However, this depends to some extent on your logging system (most people use NLog or log4net).

If on the other hand, your concern is that the job never ran in the first place because, for instance, the app/database/server was down, you could schedule FullImportJob to fire a few hours later and check if IncrementalImportJob has fired as follows:

```
//this is done from FullImportJob
//how you retrieve triggerKey will depend on whether
//you are using RAMJobStore or ADO.NET JobStore
public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
    ITrigger incImportJobTrigger = context.Scheduler.GetTrigger(triggerKey);

    //if the job has been rescheduled with a new time quartz will set this to null
    if (!incImportJobTrigger.GetPreviousFireTimeUtc().HasValue) return;

    DateTimeOffset utcTime = incImportJobTrigger.GetPreviousFireTimeUtc().Value;
    DateTime previousTireTime = utcTime.LocalDateTime;

    if (previousTireTime.Day == DateTime.Now.Day) return; 

    //IncrementalImportJob has not ran today, let's run FullImportJob 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Parsing the logs may not be an option, since Quartz is running on a "cluster" of machines for failover purposes. And I'm more concerned about the case where the `IncrementalImportJob` never ran in the designated window. The logic of dealing with the exception may still result in the FullImportJob not running as required.

Comment: Have you come across a case where IncrementalImportJob would not run in the first place (as opposed to running and crashing)? The only one I can think of is if the server or the database is down. If you are using a cluster and the scheduler is spread across multiple servers, then that is a very good failsafe implementation

Comment: Mostly maintenance windows where things doesn't go according to plan.  In theory they should never happen, but in practice they sometimes do. What if I schedule both jobs and check whether IncrementalImportJob completed successfully in FullImportJob an hour or two after IncrementalImportJob should normally complete?

Comment: Just for anyone in the future reading it. The approach to check the trigger of another job works perfect.